# Why are my specular highlights elliptical?

Tags: raytracing

I think these should be circular. I assume there is something wrong with my normals but I haven't found anything wrong with them.  Then again, finding a good test for the normals is difficult.

Here is the image:[image]

Here is my shading code for each light, leaving out the recursive part for reflections:

```
  lighting = ( hit.obj.ambient + hit.obj.emission );
  const glm::vec3 view_direction = glm::normalize(eye - hit.pos);
  const glm::vec3 reflection = glm::normalize(( static_cast<float>(2) * ( glm::dot(view_direction, hit.normal) * hit.normal ) ) - view_direction);
  for(int i = 0; i < numused; ++i)
    {

      glm::vec3 hit_to_light = (lights[i].pos - hit.pos);
      float dist = glm::length(hit_to_light);
      glm::vec3 light_direction = glm::normalize(hit_to_light);
      Ray lightray(hit.pos, light_direction);
      Intersection blocked = Intersect(lightray, scene, verbose ? verbose : false);
      if( blocked.dist >= dist)
        {
          glm::vec3 halfangle = glm::normalize(view_direction + light_direction);
          float specular_multiplier = pow(std::max(glm::dot(halfangle,hit.normal), 0.f), shininess);

          glm::vec3 attenuation_term = lights[i].rgb * (1.0f / (attenuation + dist * linear + dist*dist * quad));
          glm::vec3 diffuse_term = hit.obj.diffuse * ( std::max(glm::dot(light_direction,hit.normal) , 0.f) );
          glm::vec3 specular_term = hit.obj.specular * specular_multiplier;
        }
    }
```

And here is the line where I transform the object space normal to world space:

```
*norm = glm::normalize(transinv * glm::vec4(glm::normalize(p - sphere_center), 0));
```

Using the full phong model, instead of blinn-phong, I get teardrop highlights:

[image]

If I color pixels according to the (absolute value of the) normal at the intersection point I get the following image (r = x, g = y, b = z):
[image]

Comment: How do you transform your normals? Since you probably start with spheres and scale them non-uniformly, you need to use the transposed inverse instead of the regular transformation matrix (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924659/transformation-of-a-surface-normal) for more details)

Comment: I do use the transpose inverse to transform the normals, and I'm using `glm::transpose(glm::inverse(object_transform))` so I don' think the matrix is calculated incorrectly.  I'll add the normal transformation line to this question just in case something went wrong there.

Comment: Although it's probably still not the full solution, have you tried moving from the Blinn-Phong model (which is only an approximation) to the full Phong model, i.e. replacing `dot(halfangle,normal)` by `dot(reflection,light_direction)`?

Comment: Just added the image generated with the full phong model, but, as you thought, it does not fully resolve the issue.

Comment: The next step to debugging this might be some kind of visualization of the normals, either by directly mapping them to RGB values ((value + 1) / 2) or by sampling an environment map (i.e. cube map, ...) using the normals and comparing different scalings of the ellipsoids. Unfortunately, without further information, I cannot provide any more helpful guesses. Do the highlights work if you don't scale your objects at all?

Comment: Without any transforms or with only uniform scalings, the highlight is circular and looks as expected.  It must have something to do with the transpose inverse.

Comment: Just for completeness, could you add the code you use to compute `transinv` to your question? Also, why is your normal computed from a `vec4` and not a `vec3`?

Comment: The transinv is computed using glm like in one of the above comments.  Multiplying by a vec4 with 4th component equal to zero was just easier than writing a separate function to multiply a 4x4 by a vec3 (when working with homogeneous coordinates).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150231/discussion-between-tobias-ribizel-and-user393454).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue.  It turns out that the normals were all just slightly off, but not enough that the image colored by normals could depict it.

I found this out by computing the normals on spheres with a uniform scale and a translation.

The problem occurred in the line where I transformed the normals to world space:

```
*norm = glm::normalize(transinv * glm::vec4(glm::normalize(p - sphere_center), 0));
```

I assumed that the homogeneous coordinate would be 0 after the transformation because it was zero beforehand (rotations and scales do not affect it, and because it is 0, neither can translations). However, it is not 0 because the matrix is transposed, so the bottom row was filled with the inverse translations, causing the homogeneous coordinate to be nonzero.

The 4-vector is then normalized and the result is assigned to a 3-vector. The constructor for the 3-vector simply removes the last entry, so the normal was left unnormalized.

Here's the final picture:
[image]